# How to close a pdf file via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How to close a `PDF` file via PowerShell?

I have tried Stop-Process but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why use PoSH to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question and describe with more details what you are trying to achieve. What have you tried? What happened with `Stop-Process`?

Comment: @postanote Sorry for the late reply. Cracking the code  I guess. Open and close a file using PoSH.

Comment: No worries. The close code is shown, to open a pdf or any other file with the default viewer or app, just do this...  Start-Process -FilePath 'FullPathToWhateverFileYouNeed'

Answer (score 0):

Why use PoSH to do this? 
Are you starting a pdf in your code you need to close vs the user closing it? What pdf viewer are you using, Adobe, FoxIt. MS built-in reader...etc..? 
Is this just one pdf or multiple? Why not just close the

Just look for the PDF viewer process and close it, which ever one you were using from the example list above.

```
Get-Process -Name AcroRd32

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
429      22     9816      25476       0.28   5428   1 AcroRd32
522      49    90020     116200       1.78  17100   1 AcroRd32

Stop-Process -Name AcroRd32 -Force
```

If you trying to call a specifc file runnning in the reader, then do this (though this will still just shut down the reader)

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_process `
-Filter {name = 'AcroRd32.exe' and commandline like '%ActiveDirectoryDesignGuide%'}) |
Select CommandlIne,ProcessId | Format-List -Force

CommandlIne : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "D:\Documents\ActiveDirectoryDesignGuide.pdf"
ProcessId   : 8176

CommandlIne : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" --type=renderer /prefetch:1  
              "D:\Documents\ActiveDirectoryDesignGuide.pdf"
ProcessId   : 14484

Stop-Process -Id (Get-WmiObject win32_process `
-Filter {name = 'AcroRd32.exe' and commandline like '%ActiveDirectoryDesignGuide%'}).ProcessId -Force
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I miss AcroRd stands for Acrobat Reader.